# how to prevent users from shutdown my RDP server 2012 R2?

Tags: remote-desktop, shutdown, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a server RDP for specific users, and they shut down the server by mistake, I want to prevent these users from shutdown the server.

I have to give them administrator local and remote desktop groups.

they are Domain users, each user in a different department.

how can I prevent them from shutdown the server 2012 R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't give them the local Administrator group in the first place. Most likely your users only need a few more precise rights assignments (e.g. file ACLs or printer ACLs or similar), not the full set of Admin rights.
2. Through "Security Settings" (secpol.msc or GPO) → "Local Policies" → "User Rights Assignment", find the right "Shut down the system" and replace its 'Administrators' entry with something else that includes only real administrators.

Comment: i'll try your solution

Comment: they cannot remote desktop to this server without the administrator local Group , I tried only the Remote Desktop Group but it didn't work ,so I have no choice rather than add them to administrator Local Group ,by the way it's old windows 2012 R2

Comment: @AkramMokhtar: Being able to RDP (interactive login) is also a system right that you can grant though secpol, and is not necessarily limited to admins.

Comment: @user186 i don't understand what u mean by grant though secpol?